# Tree Structure in SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, model-view-controller

I am trying to make an android app where students can put all their courses along with assignments so they can calculate their current grade.

I don't know much about databases but I was thinking of making an SQLite Database.

The database takes in a course and each course has categories, where in each category are assignments.

so like this:

```
                          Courses
                        /       \
                     Math       Physics
                   /      \        \...
                 Tests     Exam
               /     \         \
         Test1Mark Test2Mark  ExamMark
```

Now I'm not sure if an SQLite Database is what I want because this resembles a hierarchical model rather than a basic spreadsheet.

Am I on the right track looking into SQLite, or should I be learning something else?

Answer (score 1):

```
Courses
---------
_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
courseName TEXT,
[... some other data you need ...]

CoursesTests
-----
_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
courseId INT, -- It will refer to Courses(_id)
testName TEXT,
[... some other data you need ...]

CoursesExams
-----
_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
courseId INT, -- It will refer to Courses(_id)
examName TEXT,
[... some other data you need ...]
```

So you can create course `Math`, with `_id` (auto_increment) suppose 1.

So to add a Exam inside `Math` insert into `CoursesExams` a new row with `courseId` = 1.

Same for `Tests` and for other courses.